# Method for adding according to form Btns

Tags: c#, winforms, class

Using Winforms C#

is there a way to reuse a method but when the user selects another button on the form, the methods adds a figure to the old figure. Let me explain more.

I have a class with the method "Addition"

```
`double weightIn = 0.01;

public double addition(double weightOut)
{
    return weightOut = (weightIn + 0.12);
}`
```

I have two Btns. Btn1 and Btn2.

When I select Btn1, I have the method executing, giving me a result of 0.13

I need it so when i select Btn2 it changes, adding the 0.12 onto that result.

Also, I would need it to go back to 0.13 if Btn 1 was selected again.

How would I go about doing this? I have tried using flags1, flags2 and doing it that way, but having no success.

Thanks

Comment: So, button 1 computes 0.13, and when you click button 2, you want 0.25, but if you click button 1 again you want 0.13? What is the logic behind this? It sounds like button 2 should just be a checkbox or something.

Comment: You should provide the logic behind this it would help us find out what's on your mind.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Its because I need the figure to change according to the Btn selected, but I do not want it adding an extra 0.12 on if Btn 1 is selected again. 

eventually I will have 6 Btns. Btn1 to be 0.01 + 0.12. Btn2 to be that result + 0.12, Btn3 to be Btn2's result + 0.12 etc.

but once that calculation has been made, I dont want it to be made again, I need the result to stay the same, so Btn1, once clicked again stays are 0.13 and does not increment by 0.12 each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use booleans (flags) to determine if it has been added already, maybe changing the background color of the button to reflect the status.  As someone else stated already checkboxes sounds like it would make more sense, but I will do what I can here.

you could also use an array of doubles which corresponds to the the buttons.

```
double[] bttn=new double[6]{0,0,0,0,0,0};

double weighin {get { 
                      double temp=0;
                      foreach (double d in bttn) 
                      temp=temp+d;
                      return d;
                     }
                }
```

Then in the button Click event

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch ((Control)sender).Name)
    {
        //so what happens here is, if the value is 0 make it the value indicated else make it 0
        case "Button0":bttn[0] = bttn[0]==0 ? 0.01 : 0;
                       break;
        case "Button1":bttn[1] = bttn[0]==0 ? 0.12 : 0;
                       break;
        case "Button2":bttn[2] = bttn[0]==0 ? 0.24 : 0;
                       break;
        case "Button3":bttn[3] = bttn[0]==0 ? 0.48 : 0;
                       break;
        case "Button4":bttn[4] = bttn[0]==0 ? 0.96 : 0;
                       break;
        case "Button5":bttn[5] = bttn[0]==0 ? 1.92 : 0;
                       break;
    }
}
```

Then to use it you simply use weighin.  It will add all the elements of the array.

```
double MyWeight = weighin;
```

I did not test the syntax of any of this code